# Microsoft technical interview: Matrix Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, pseudocode

I recently had an interview in which the interviewer gave me some pseudocode and asked questions related to it. Unfortunately, I was not able to answer his questions due to lack of preparation. Due to time constraint, I could not ask him the solution for that problem. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me and help me understand the problem so I can improve for the future. Below is the pseudocode:

```
A sample state of ‘a’: 
[[   2, NULL,    2, NULL], 
 [   2, NULL,    2, NULL], 
 [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL], 
 [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]]

FUNCTION foo()
  FOR y = 0 to 3 
    FOR x = 0 to 3
      IF a[x+1][y] != NULL
        IF a[x+1][y] = a[x][y]:
          a[x][y] := a[x][y]*2
          a[x+1][y] := NULL
        END IF
        IF a[x][y] = NULL
          a[x][y] := a[x+1][y]
          a[x+1][y] := NULL
        END IF
      END IF
    END FOR
  END FOR
END FUNCTION
```

The interviewer asked me:

1. What is the issue with the above code and how would I fix it?
2. Once corrected, what does function foo do? Please focus on the result of the function, not the details of the implementation.
3. How could you make foo more generic? Explain up to three possible generalization directions and describe a strategy for each, no need to write the code!

I mentioned to him:

- The state of the matrix looks incorrect because an integer matrix cannot have null values. By default they are assigned `0`, `false` for Boolean and `null` for the reference type.
- Another issue with the above code is at `IF a[x+1][y] != NULL`, the condition will produce an array index out-of-bounds error when `x` equals `3`.

But I felt the interviewer was looking for something else in my answer and was not satisfied with the explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you played the game "2048" ([link to game](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/))? If not, this question will likely not make much intuitive sense to you, and because of that, I think it's a poor interview question.

What this attempts to do is simulate one step of the 2048 game where the numbers go upward. Numbers will move upward by one cell unless they hit another number or the matrix border (think of gravity pulling all numbers upward). If the two numbers are equal, they combine and produce a new number (their sum).

*Note: this isn't exactly one step of the 2048 game because numbers only move one cell upward, while in the game they move "all they way" until they hit something else. To get a step of the 2048 game, you'd repeat the given function until no more changes occur.*

The issue in the code is, as you mentioned, the array index out-of-bounds. It should be fixed by iterating over `x = 0 to 2` instead.

To make this more general, you have to be creative:

1. The main generalization is that it should take a "direction" parameter. (Again you wouldn't know this if you haven't played the 2048 game yourself.) Instead of gravity pulling numbers upward, gravity can pull numbers in any of the 4 cardinal directions.
2. Maybe the algorithm shouldn't check for `NULL` but should check against some other sentinel value (which is another input).
3. It's also pretty easy to generalize this to larger matrices.
4. Maybe there should be some other rule that dictates when numbers get combined, and how precisely they get combined (not necessarily 2 times the first). These rules can be given in the form of lambdas.

---

As for this part of your answer:

> integer matrix cannot have null values, by default they are assigned 0, false for Boolean and null for the reference type

That is largely dependent on the language being used, so I wouldn't say this is an error in the pseudocode (which isn't supposed to be in any particular language). For instance, in weakly-typed languages you can certainly have a matrix with `int` and `NULL` values.

---

You don't mention what you said about the function's behavior. If I were the interviewer, I would want to see someone "think out loud" and realize at least the following:

- The code is trying to compare each element with the one below it.
- Nothing happens unless the lower element is `NULL`.
- If the two elements are equal, then the lower one is replaced with `NULL` and the upper element becomes twice as large.
- If the top element is `NULL`, then the lower non-`NULL` element "moves" to the top element's place.

These observations about the code are straightforward to obtain just by reading the source code. Whether or not you make sense of these "rules" and notice that it's (similar to) the 2048 game is largely dependent on whether you've played the game before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the python code for the same program. I have fixed the index out of bound issue in this code. Hope this helps.

```
null = 0
array = [[2,null,2,null],[2,null,2,null],[null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null]]
range = [0,1,2]
for y in range:
   for x in range:
       if array[x+1][y] != null:
           if array[x+1][y] == array[x][y]:
               array[x][y] = array[x][y]*2
               array[x+1][y] = null
           if array[x][y] == null:
               array[x][y] = array[x+1][y]
               array[x+1][y] = null
print(array)
```

Answer (score -1):

> Once corrected, what does function foo do? Please focus on the result of the function, not the details of the implementation

The output will be :

```
4 null 4 null
null null null null
null null null null
null null null null
```